# Function to generate frequency table of individual values given a data frame with a column of comma-separated values in R

Tags: r, dplyr

**Sample data**

```
df <- tibble(x = c("c('gene1', 'gene2', 'gene2', 'gene3')",
                   "c('gene3', 'gene4', 'gene5'"))
# A tibble: 2 x 1
  x                                    
  <chr>                                
1 c('gene1', 'gene2', 'gene2', 'gene3')
2 c('gene3', 'gene4', 'gene5'
```

Yes, each value in this column `x` is indeed a paste of c(). The original algorithm used outputs a dataframe containing a column of c() strings of gene names.

**Desired Output**

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  gene   freq
  <chr> <dbl>
1 gene1     1
2 gene2     2
3 gene3     2
4 gene4     1
5 gene5     1
```

**Fast** or **tidyverse**-based solutions would be welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be better to split the column 'x' with `separate_rows`.  By default the `sep` will use the `,` as split, then we `filter` out the `"c"` and blank `""` elements before doing the `count`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
     separate_rows(x) %>% 
     filter(!x %in% c("c", "")) %>%
     count(gene = x, name = 'freq')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#  gene   freq
#* <chr> <int>
#1 gene1     1
#2 gene2     2
#3 gene3     2
#4 gene4     1
#5 gene5     1
```

Comment: I didn't know about `separate_rows()`, that's a neat function!